# Blender CUDA Rendering

Tags: gpu

I am using Blender 2.66a a nVidia GT 520 and Ubuntu 13.10. I wanted to enable GPU rendering. But in the System Panel there is no 'CUDA' Option.
 I know that this Card supports CUDA, because I have tested it on Windows 7 (dual- boot) too and it worked.
I installed the proprietary GPU driver using

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

**Any ideas why it doesnt work?**
*Thanks in the preface*

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using that version of Blender?

Comment: **Yes**, its the latest Version, thats available in the official repository!

Comment: I have tried it using the latest Version (2.69) and *it worked*, but GPU rendering takes more time and CPU rendering. **Do I need to adjust some settings ?**

Comment: It's really odd that GPU would take longer than CPU. If you're on a laptop, it's entirely possible that Blender is mistakenly using your onboard graphics, rather than your nVidia card. Also keep in mind that you have to select which card to use in the User Preferences, as well as choosing GPU rather than CPU in the Render panel. It'd be nice if these two settings would affect each other, or at least provide a warning, but they didn't the last time I made this mistake.

Comment: This doc: http://www.blenderguru.com/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/ will also help you trouble shoot some things. E.g. tiles with a size that is a power of 2 are MUCH more efficient than tiles of arbitrary size.

Comment: @Matt Can you prove that? I did some testing [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/best-tile-size-for-blender-internal-renderer-and-cycles) and I saw no evidence of any speedup.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll post some of my benchmarks when I get a chance. In short, I usually see a 10% decrease in render times if I use tile dimensions that are powers of 2, versus dividing my image into equal portions. Part of the problem is that render time depends on a LOT of other things too. Even the order in which the tiles are rendered can have an impact on render times. I'll try and provide some examples...

Comment: Ok, in the `User Preferences/System` I switched the `Compute Device` to `CUDA / nVidia GT 520`, also I set `Device` (in the Renderpanel) to `GPU Compute` (Supported Feature Set) 

GPU Rendering now takes 6.67 seconds (Tile Size 256:256) and CPU Rendering the same scene takes 1.85 seconds (Tile Size 16:16)

Is there an other possibility to speed up GPU Rendering, or should I instead use CPU Rendering.

@Matt **Thank you**

Comment: @Peter Parker That's really.... REALLY odd. It's easier for me to believe that you have a really strange scene, than to believe CPU is actually faster than GPU, IWC yes, I do believe there's a way to speed it up, I just don't know what it is. I'd love to take a look at the scene you're rendering and see if it fits one of the strange cases I've come across.

Comment: That's really weird. Is your GPU from the 70's or 80's and your CPU from the future? While this is a duplicate of what Vader posted above, this would be an interesting discussion to continue, or even an interesting question in its own right.

Comment: @Matt Sorry I didnt answer... this is the file (http://www.file-upload.net/download-8706409/kugel-auf-karo.blend.html)

Comment: No worries, I'll try to take a look at it this evening and let you know what I find.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I don't have any good answers for you :-/ It's not one of the weird situations. I rendered it 4 times. For CPU with tiles @ 64x64, I got 7:19. For GPU @ 64x64, I got 1:49. Then I changed the tile size. CPU @ 512x512 I got 8:26, and for GPU @ 512x512 I got 1:19. The only thing I can figure is that there's a bottleneck between your GPU and mobo and that using tiles so small is causing it to swap RAM/VRAM back and forth more often than it needs to, and the overhead in swapping that RAM is killing your GPU render time. Try a higher tile size, but IDK what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Matt, especially if you are on a laptop. Whether you are on a laptop or a desktop PC, I would check the following settings in Blender. Also, when using GPU rendering in Cycles, make sure to check the settings in the Properties tab -> Performance -> Tiles. By default the two numbers under the "Tiles" settings usually are 64 x 64 (pixels). If you are able to get your Nvidia GT 520 video card to work, try bumping up those numbers to 200 x 80 and see if that helps. The other thing i recommend checking is the "Sampling" menu in the Properties panel. If the final render has a high sample number (i.e. - 800 or above), that can also cause render time to be slow. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

CUDA level support is different between GPUs, see [this link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus). Higher CUDA compliance results in better speedup. As I remember, Blender needs at least CUDA 2.0 features, but higher level of CUDA compliance is better.

Earlier Blenders did not even allow using CUDA below 2.0.

It seems that your GPU is CUDA 2.1 compliant, check if your CUDA driver is the latest, too. My guess is that your driver shows a supported version < 2.0 to Blender 2.66a, and so Blender 2.66a did not show CUDA support.

Also, others' comment about optimizations are also very valid.