# Orange squares appearing on render?

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render a scene in Blender, and as of yesterday (it was not doing this when I was working on it 2-3 days ago), I am seeing orange squares dancing around the rendered image. Google tells me that these are render tiles (I think), but what are they, why are they there, and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: You mean while you are rendering? Those just show what tile is currently being rendered.

Comment: If you are trying to render an animation, you need to specify that. You can view your animation by slicking 'view animation', or you can create an AVI.;http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-in-blender

Comment: I'm not actually trying to render an animation, just a still image. That's another issue I'm having, blender seems to be rendering frames of an animation when I don't intend to create an animation. It goes on and on with rendering and re-rendering. Is there a way to stop it from rendering so many times? I don't think I keyed animations at any point.

Comment: @user2828965 What render engine are you using? If you are using BI, do you have motion blur or FSAA enabled? Or multiple render layers?

Comment: Figured out what was going on with the rendering of an animation. I was actually hitting ctrl-F12 (render animation) as opposed to just F12 (render image), hence the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are just indicating the currently rendering tiles:

[image]

AFAIK there is no way to turn them off, other than disabling tiled rendering (anyway, IMO they are quite useful).

To disable tiled rendering in cycles, enable *progressive refine* in *Render settings > performance*:

[image]

To disable tiled rendering in BI, make the tile size at least as large as your render:

[image]

Note that disabling tiled rendering will increase render times, as in most cases rendering many small images is faster than rendering one large image. See [Are there any advantages of bigger/smaller tiles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6329/599).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What's weird is that I never noticed them when I first started working on my model. Do the orange tiles become more often visible when you have a more complex model?

Comment: @user2828965 No, they are always there.. The only time I can think of when they weren't there in older versions of blender (I think they were added somewhere around ~2.64? I'd need to look that up though).