# Blender only renders in one Tile

Tags: rendering, tilesize

I want to render a 4000x5000 picture.

I used a one-tiled (4000x5000 px) test render, with 20% resolution-scaling for a test over night.

But now no matter what tilesize i set.

No matter the resolution scaling.

It won't go back to multiple tiles.

Switching between CPU and GPU and using both auto-tile and manual settings, didnt work.

Comment: add a screenshot of render settings

Comment: Sounds pretty tileable ;) What's your question? Suggest to enable *Auto Tile Size Addon*, output as *OpenEXR* file, disable *Progressive Refine* and enable *Save Buffers* for such image dimensions. There no reason to render the image in one big chunk...

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestions. Disable Progressive Refine and enable Save Buffers was the solution. But sometimes it seems, every question without a screenshot isn't worthy ob beeing read fully. "using both auto-tile and manual settings, didnt work." Your first suggestion: "Auto Tile Size Addon". Nice thank you.Also rendering an image in one big chunk is a comon technique if you dont know how long you can render, but still want a full image, without tiles missing, when you come back to it.

Comment: There is no reason and that's not any common technique @JensClar. *Progressive refine* is for preview purposes in combination with the [Render Border](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/301/31447) (waiting until you get enough samples for a small section of the image) in order to render the *final image* in tiles, especially when it comes to big images. Also notice that each finished tile can directly saved to the EXR file and the rendering is probably faster in general. Anyway, glad I could help. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3120/31447

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51888/what-advantages-in-using-progressive-rendering and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6329/are-there-any-advantages-of-bigger-smaller-tiles