# Cycles Render - Rendering Time

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I have an iMac and I'd like to make it faster. I've made some modifications following some tutorials, but the process is still very slow, and I feel like the real change would be to set GPU instead of CPU; so is it possible to do that on iMac? Is it normal that to render one frame the program takes more than a minute? To render 40 frames I waited for more than 40 minutes..

Comment: 1 frame a minute is really quite fast. With a complex scene and high render resolution, renders can take days or weeks (especially if you stop the render while using the computer for other things). As far as GPU rendering goes, it depends on what kind of GPU your imac has. If it supports [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products#opencl) (or even better, [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)), then it should be at least *possible*, but not necessarily faster. See [this question for more detail](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7485/599)

Comment: **Rendering takes time**. Complex scenes render slower than simple ones.  GPU rendering **might** be faster in some cases, but do not expect miracles. The GPUs on imacs are quite limited, and those that use AMD cards have still have compatibility /drive issues . You can optimize your scene (bake, simplify, remesh, decimate, etc...) but ultimately you'll have to be patient. read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24272/gpu-slower-than-cpu and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46050/how-can-i-optimize-my-render-times/46055#46055

Comment: Actually it's not a complex scene at all, there is practically an imported character from makehuman and a uv sphere

Comment: Rendering does take time, but check this out as well: http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/ Changing the tile size, as mentioned, is the only truly affective speeder-upper that has absolutely zero trade-offs.

Comment: Change the samples down to increase speed and chance of artifacts and other horrible looking dots. Close programs, and finally keep your imac cool.