# Full render in one tile - solution for lack of memory?

Tags: rendering, memory-management, multiresolution, tilesize

I created super complicated scene using 8gb out of 6gb of vram. On the way of trying to reduce memory usage I saw many times my gpu rendering only one tile, with all samples, and skipping rest of the tiles with message at the end "out of memory". Right now it hit me that I can set a tile to a size of full render. It would probably render quicker with 256 by 256 tiles. It just finished... and looks normal. Has anyone done it before? Or is it a common technique only I didn't know? What are the cons? Does it differ from properly rendered tiles?

Comment: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing

Comment: @cegaton I know about it, I have read this article already, unfortunately it is impossible in my scene

Comment: Rendering one huge tile is bad. It is not optimal in term of speed nor from memory consumption point of view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Tile Size for Blender Internal Renderer and Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/best-tile-size-for-blender-internal-renderer-and-cycles)

Comment: Rendering in one tile is more optimal then running out of memory, for sure. :D

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I am rather asking whether this one tile rendered before gpu runs out of memory is any different from "properly" rendered one